# Is there a Python built-in that can select agnostically from either a dictionary or an object?

Tags: python, object, dictionary, selector

I'm looking for a function `f(x,selector)` that acts like `x.get(selector)` when `x` is a dictionary and `getattr(x, selector)` when `x` is a class instance. Easy enough to write, but is there one built in?

Comment: dicts are objects too. What should `f(d, 'keys')` return? `d.keys` or `d['keys']`?

Comment: This doesn't exist as a built-in because in Python it would be very odd to not care about the difference between attributes and keys.  What data are you dealing with where you don't know which one you want?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no built-in.

Just could just exception handling:

```
def f(x, selector):
    try:
        # Assume dictionary and has .get() method
        return x.get(selector)
    except AttributeError:
        # Assumption incorrect, no .get() method present
        return getattr(x, selector)
```

or swap the two lines if you want attributes to be checked for first.

Another variant, supporting a default:

```
_sentinel = object()

def f(x, selector, default=_sentinel):
    try:
        # Assume mapping access is supported
        result = x[selector]
    except KeyError:
        # key missing, fall through to default handling
        pass
    except TypeError:
        # Assumption incorrect, not a mapping, fall back to attributes
        result = getattr(x, selector, default)
    if result is _sentinel:
        raise KeyError(selector)
    return default
```

but you could also collapse the `KeyError` handling into the second `TypeError` handler and fall back to `getattr()` first.

Take into account however that you are trying to mix two namespaces here; keys and attributes can collide, and attribute literals are more limited than keys, etc. Most Python code doesn't try to mix the two, which is *why* there is no built-in for this task.

Comment: swap the lines and change the exception to KeyError.

Comment: @PauloScardine: no, `dict.get()` doesn't raise a `KeyError`. And if there is no `.get()` method, that'll raise an `AttributeError`..

Comment: I would use `return x[selector]` instead of `x.get`, just in case the object is not a dict but has a get property by coincidence, and check `IndexError` in order to handle list-like objects.

Comment: @PauloScardine USing `get()` gives the option to use a default value if there is no value in the dictionary for that key yet. The OP didn't ask what to do if the key isn't in the dictionary, just to change the behavior if it is/isn't a dictionary. GEtting `None` from the dict could perfectly reasonable behavior.

Comment: @PauloScardine: you are approaching why there is no built-in for this; attributes and keys are *two different, separate namespaces*, and you'll easily find ways to end up with conflicts between the two. Using `x[selector]` is a tradeoff, just like `x.get(selector)` is an equally valid tradeoff. Different usecases will make different choices, and the general practice is just not common enough to have Python worry about creating a one-size-fits-all tool.

Comment: Well, `x.get` looks extremely "ducky" to me. Even in the standard lib there are plenty of classes with totally unrelated `.get` methods.

Comment: @georg: of course it is ducky, it uses duck typing. Again, since the OP is trying to mix two namespaces, clashes are going to occur whatever way you try to approach it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: of course, but I'm not sure the OP will be happy when he passes, say, a `requests.request` object to your function and it bravely starts making `get` http requests. ))

Comment: @georg: and then you use `x[selector]` and pass in a list and it fails, or you use attribute access first and you cannot find the `setdefault` key, etc. It'll break one way or another.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: and the moral of the story is that you can't get around an explicit type check here (`if isinstance(collections.Mapping...`. Duck typing is usually fine, but `get` is just too common.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to check type of object

```
def f(x, selector):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
       return x.get(selector)
    return getattr(x, selector)
```

Comment: But, i think Martijn answer's is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [297]: class Foo:
   .....:     def __init__(self):
   .....:         self.bar=5
   .....:         


In [298]: def f(x, selector):
   .....:     if hasattr(x, 'get'):
   .....:         g = operator.itemgetter(selector)
   .....:     else:  # x is an object
   .....:         g = operator.attrgetter(selector)
   .....:     return g(x)
   .....: 

In [299]: x = Foo()

In [300]: f(x, 'bar')
Out[300]: 5

In [301]: d = {char:i for i,char in enumerate('asdf')}

In [302]: f(d, 'a')
Out[302]: 0

In [303]: d
Out[303]: {'a': 0, 's': 1, 'd': 2, 'f': 3}
```

Comment: Why use `operator.itemgetter()` / `operator.attrgetter()` at all if all you are going to do is call it immediately? Why not just use indexing or attribute access with `getattr()` *directly* rather than use the indirection?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It was just a thought. I like building functions that I can later use. Granted, that's probably overkill in this scenario, but I like building functions within functions - it's oddly exciting